Check workbook to see if it contains any pivot charts
Looking to simply check a workbook to see if it contains any pivot chart. No looking for anything fancy, just something that checks and tells me yes or no.
I tried to disect code but the only thing i can find deals with name…

Do you need this info for a closed workbook or an already opened workbook?

An open workbook

The following code will dump all charts of all worksheets into the immediate window (if it is not visible, press Ctrl+G to show it).
Depending if it is a Pivot chart or not, a different text is printed as prefix - if you are only interested in pivot charts, comment out the line in the Else-branch.
Sub PrintPivotChartNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim co As chartobject
        For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
            ' When PivotLayout is set, it is a Pivot chart
            If Not co.Chart.PivotLayout Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Pivot Chart: " & ws.Name, co.Name
            Else
                Debug.Print "Regular Chart: " & ws.Name, co.Name
            End If
        Next co
    Next ws
End Sub

This is what was printed on my little test workbook - pivot with chart is on sheet2 and a copy of that pivot chart is on sheet 3, while sheet 1 has 2 regular charts:
Regular Chart: Sheet1       Chart 2
Regular Chart: Sheet1       Testchart
Pivot Chart: Sheet2         Chart 1
Pivot Chart: Sheet3         Chart 1

Update: I couldn't generate a case where the code above code didn't work, I never got an error checking if the PivotLayout is Nothing. However, as others state that they got an error, here's an updated version:
Sub PrintPivotChartNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim co As ChartObject
        For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
            ' When PivotLayout is set, it is a Pivot chart
            Dim pl As PivotLayout
            Set pl = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set pl = co.Chart.PivotLayout
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not pl Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Pivot Chart: " & ws.Name, co.Name
            Else
                Debug.Print "Regular Chart: " & ws.Name, co.Name
            End If
        Next co
    Next ws
End Sub


On my Office 365 on Windows 10 accessing PivotLayout for non-pivot charts produces "Run-time error '445': Object doesn't support this action". It should be covered by the `On Error' statement.

I tested it on another computer, it produces the same error. This conforms my experience with VBA. I wonder how this ``co.Chart.PivotLayout Is Nothing` works.

PivotChart can be detected based on PivotLayout property which should be accessible. The simple subroutine below prints names of pivot charts on the active sheet:
Sub PrintPivotChartNames()
  Dim chartobject As Object, pl As Object
  On Error GoTo NonPivotChartError
  For Each chartobject In Sheet1.ChartObjects
    Set pl = chartobject.chart.PivotLayout
    Debug.Print chartobject.chart.Name
Continue1:
  Next
  Exit Sub
NonPivotChartError:
  Resume Continue1
End Sub


Thank you. Is there a way to find it at the workbook level? Just curious.

Since charts are embedded into worksheets, they can be accessed over worksheets only: first, iterate through worksheets For Each asheet In Worksheets; second, access sheet's chart collection For Each chartobject In asheet.ChartObjects and further as per code above.

Here's another take on solving your problem.  It appears Pivot Charts have a Type of 3.  Leveraging this simplifies the code a little and works without any error handling.
Option Explicit

Private Function hasPivotCharts() As Boolean
   Dim sh As Object
   Dim co As Object
   
   For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      For Each co In sh.ChartObjects
        If co.Chart.Type = 3 Then
           hasPivotCharts = True
           Exit Function
        End If
      Next
   Next
End Function

EDIT:  The above doesn't work for all chart types.
Try combining the approaches of @FunThomas and @rotabor:
Private Function hasPivotCharts() As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim sh As Object
   Dim co As Object
   Dim pl As Object
   
   For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      For Each co In sh.ChartObjects
        Set pl = co.Chart.PivotLayout
        
        If Not pl Is Nothing Then
           hasPivotCharts = True
           Exit Function
        End If
      Next
   Next
End Function


It's not correct.

How so?  It works good for me.

I got -4102 for type 3-D Pie, 4 for any line chart. It looks like the chart type category.
